# Easily edit questions when reviewing the answers

Tags: feature-request, review

Many times it seems that when reviewing an answer (in the review pane), when I expand the question, there is no edit button, just endless white space. Therefore, if I want to edit the question it seems that I have to open a separate tab every time.

As a new feature, would it be possible to incorporate this into the interface?

Comment: I think if it garners some upvotes here first, then I'll ask to move it, otherwise no point really.

Comment: Isn't inline editing working for you?

Comment: Inline editing (for both questions and answers) has been common for some time, what browser are you using? I can simultaneously edit a question and answer at the same using the latest release of Firefox.

Comment: Chrome 17.0.942.0 dev-m. @slhck How am I supposed to inline edit?

Comment: @soandos Just click the `edit` button on a post?

Comment: @slhck So if I am reviewing an answer in the review pane, and I click edit, I can edit the answer, but I don't see the button to edit the question...

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one who didn't get this question the first time I read it :-)

Comment: @DanielBeck, I assume that edit I made to the first line clears up the confusion?

Comment: @soandos You should emphasize that you're reviewing *answers* and want to edit their related *questions*.

Comment: Now I see. Definitely makes sense, and I was wondering the same.

Comment: @DanielBeck clearer? Or still not clear?

Comment: Well *I* understood the question in its original form already ;-) But yeah, now it's very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Is that one extra <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the question title too much in this very specific situation?

This is certainly possible, but I wouldn't give this feature request a high priority if it just replaces one click.

Also, as it's just the question body rendered. I believe it requires some fiddling to get it working. What about the other links that are there, like flagging and commenting?

Comment: For the question I have no options.